# Where should AND and OR be placed in multi-line conditional statements?

Tags: coding-style, conditional-statements

A simple coding standard question:

Where should AND and OR be placed in conditional statements?

Option 1:

```
if (x = 1 
    AND y = 2
    AND z = 3)

if (x = 1 
    && y = 2
    && z = 3)

if (x = 1 
    OR y = 2
    OR z = 3)

if (x = 1 
    || y = 2
    || z = 3)
```

Option 2:

```
if (x = 1 AND 
    y = 2 AND
    z = 3)

if (x = 1 &&
    y = 2 &&
    z = 3)

if (x = 1 OR
    y = 2 OR
    z = 3

if (x = 1 ||
    y = 2 ||
    z = 3)
```

I personally prefer option 1, since it allows you quickly comment out certain conditions - i.e. with "//" in most scripting languages, but I see option 2 more often, especially in code formatters.

Is there a standard?

What do you prefer?

Comment: Some coding standards have a word on this, but each applies only to one language...

Comment: Huh? I'm completely confused why this question was closed! I'm just looking for opinions here to help me decide my own standards....

Comment: The reason given for closing seems pretty clear. Many of the answers have told you the same thing. All anyone can say on this is subjective opinions, and that's not what this site is for (it may fare better at programmers.stackexchange.com, but even they only accept ["good subjective"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)).

Comment: If anyone WOULD like to discuss this... http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/84650/styling-compound-and-or-if-statements

Answer (score 4):

In "Code Complete," 2nd ed., pp 754-755, Steve McConnell lists the advantages of both patterns of line continuation.

The first identifies incomplete lines, but the operators are hidden in a ragged row.

The second highlights the operators. This can be important if the operators differ.

Compare:

```
  float total = ticketSalesBefore + 
                ticketSalesOnDayOfConcert + 
                tShirtSales -
                finesFromLocalPolice;
```

to:

```
  float total = ticketSalesBefore
                + ticketSalesOnDayOfConcert
                + tShirtSales
                - finesFromLocalPolice;
```

I personally prefer the second, and recommended including it during a review of McConnell's draft for that chapter.

Comment: -1 for what? Care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1, absolutely, for the same reasons you mentioned.  Easy to comment out, easy to duplicate, etc.

However, if they are small conditionals like you mentioned, I would put them all on one line.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Option 1 because it highlights the tests. For Python coding I generally agree with [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but they go with Option 2 for this one.